# How to do a feedback loop calculation in r that one result affect the other?

Tags: r, loops, time-series

I am having difficulties to build a time-series based feed back loop in R.
Since the dataset is too large, it's hard to share my code here.
In short, I have a variable "stock" is calculated annually and based on the vintage for age 1:30. Once I have the result of the year's stock, I need to calculate the "sales" for the year. Then the sales for the year is equal to the vintage[age1]next year.
It's a sequential calculation with different variables. I could not find a way that R can automatically update the results with the updated inputs.
Any thoughts will be much appreciated!

Here is an example of the question

```
vintage<-data.frame("Year"=c(1980:2030))
for (i in 1:nrow(vintage)){
 for (j in 2:31){
  vintage[i,j]=runif(1,min=19000,max=500000)
  colnames(vintage)[j]=paste("age_",j-1)
   }
  }
replacement<-vintage["Year"]
 for(i in 1:nrow(replacement)){
  for (j in 2:32){
   replacement[i,j]=runif(1,min=0,max=1)
   colnames(replacement)[j]=paste("age_",j-1)
   }
  }
replacement_distribution<-vintage["Year"]
 for (i in 1:nrow(replacement_distribution)){
  for (j in 2:31){
   replacement_distribution[i,j]=vintage[i,j]*replacement[i,j+1]
  }
 }
for (i in 1:nrow(vintage)){
 for(j in 2:31){
   if(j==2){
    vintage[i,j]=(rowSums(replacement_distribution[i- 
     1,c(2:31)])+rowSums(vintage[i-1,c(2:31)]))/5
     }
      else{
       vintage[i,j]=vintage[i-1,j-1]*(1-replacement[i,j])
    }
   }
  }
```

as you can see, this code is lengthy and not working. What I want is to update two data frame in sequential order. Meaning once the vintage distribution in 1980 is calculated, then the replacement distribution for that year will be calculated based on that result. Then the results of this two will be fed into the age1's calculation in 1981. 
I've tried multiple method (sapply/lapply), but they made all calculations done at the same time, so the results didn't match.

Comment: Can you try to find some way to make a smaller reprex (representative example) of your data please? It often makes it a lot easier for other people to find solution when they can see what you're working on.

Nested for loops are generally a bad idea, they make it easy to make errors. Have you tried cumulative arithmetic functions, e.g. `cumsum()`? Often it's also easier when you break a problem into small pieces and work on them one-by-one, before writing a more complicated nested code.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe with detail how the two dataframes are related and what operations are being used. This seems rather vague at the moment. You talk about "sales" but there are no columns named "sales".

Comment: Hi, @AdamB.,thanks for the comments and I am working on it to see if I can find a better way to make it easier. Will be back later.